# Does any one know what these marks are on my ceramic hob and how to clean them?

Tags: cleaning

[image]I have tried using astonish hob cleaner and white vinegar and baking soda but the mark is still there?[image]

Answer (score 1):

Those look like scuffs and chips on the ceramic surface. If you can feel deep dips in the surface, then you've got severe chips that might affect the integrity of the surface under heat stress.

Any metal cookware harder than the ceramic, especially materials with sharp or irregular surfaces like cast iron, can cause this.

Try using a glass top cleaner with micro-abrasive polishing particles to see if the marks can be removed and aren't scuffs and chips. Improper cleaning technique can cause or worsen damage - regular abrasive pads like the scrubbing side of some sponges can do this with enough pressure, or if there's grit on the surface from cooking/etc.

I use the Weiman brand kit (multiple options on their site: https://weiman.com/glass-cooktop) with the cleaning paste, scrub pad, and scraping razor for most cleaning.

---

Edit: the Astonish cleaner you used has quartz as its abrasive polishing agent. If those marks aren't gone, then it's likely surface damage on the ceramic.

[image: Astonish ingredient sheet]

Comment: Some speculation: the grouping of the chips toward the 7-8 o'clock perimeter of the surface suggests significant movement of cookware in that corner - left-handed sautéing/stir-frying?